# Gelfand's transform for noncommutative $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, c-star-algebras, gelfand-duality, affine-hecke-algebras

Please excuse me if this is well-known, I am not very familiar with the general theory of $C^*$-algebras.

Let $A$ be a unital separable liminal $C^*$-algebra (in the case I am interested in, completions of affine Hecke algebras, all irreducible representations are even finite dimensional) with dual $\hat{A}$. Let $E$ be the fiber bundle over $\hat{A}$ whose fiber over an irreducible representation $\pi$ is the corresponding Hilbert space $H_\pi$, and let $K(E)$ be the fiber bundle whose fiber at $\pi$ is $K(H_\pi)$ (compact operators).
Any element $a\in A$ defines in the obvious way a section $s_a$ of the bundle $K(E) \to \hat{A}$.

Is there a natural topology on $K(E)$ such that all $s_a$ are continuous and such that the map $a \mapsto s_a$ defines an isomorphism of $C^*$-algebras from $A$ to the algebra of continuous sections of $K(E)$? Or if it's not true in general, are there natural conditions on $A$ under which it is?

Note that in the case where $A$ is commutative, $K(E)$ is the trivial bundle $\hat{A} \times \mathbb{C}$ and this is just the usual Gelfand's isomorphism.

Comment: I don't quite understand what a liminal $C^{\ast}$-algebra is, but I think $E$ and $K(E)$ need not be fiber bundles. In the $C^{\ast}$-algebra $C([0, 1], M_2)$ of continuous functions $[0, 1] \to M_2$, consider the subalgebra of functions $f$ such that $f(0)$ is a scalar. Then I think $\hat{A}$ is $[0, 1]$ and the dimensions of both $E$ and $K(E)$ change from $2$ resp. $4$ to $1$ as we approach the origin from the right. (This comes from an old homework assignment I was given in a class taught by Voiculescu.)

Comment: I agree with @QiaochuYuan - indeed something very similar to this algebra arises as the group Cstar algebra of ${\mathbb Z}\rtimes {\mathbb Z}_2$. I am also not an expert, merely an occasional user, but I think that _semicontinuity_ rather than continuity turns out to be the more natural and useful condition to put on sections of the bundle over the primitive ideal space

Comment: @YemonChoi Do you have a reference for what $\hat{A}$ and $E$ look like for this particular algebra? I'm looking at Iwahori-Hecke algebras, so this should be the easiest case of type $A_1$ and parameter $q=1$.

Comment: I think this example might be in Davidson's book on Cstar algebras, but I am not sure. It is also worth noting that the topology on A-hat is usually non-Hausdorff. If you want a general reference for the basic properties of A-hat and the primitive ideal space Prim(A), which coincide for liminal algebras but can be different in general, then I find Murphy's book on Cstar algebras much more readable than Dixmier's book even though the latter is used as a canonical reference

Comment: Another POV on this example ($A = {\rm C}^\ast(G)$ where $G={\mathbb Z}\rtimes {\mathbb Z}_2$) is to use Mackey theory/induced representations to determine $\hat{G}$, which is the same as $\hat{A}$. Writing $N$ for the copy of ${\mathbb Z}$ inside $G$, we can take $\chi\in\hat{N}$ and induce it to a representation ${\rm Ind} \chi :G \to U_2({\mathbb C})$. This induced rep is irreducible unless $\chi$ happens to be fixed by the action of ${\mathbb Z}_2$ on $\hat{N}$, and the fixed points correspond to $\{\pm 1\}$ on the unit circle; for these two choice of $\chi$ the induced rep splits...

Comment: ... and it turns out, although one needs to check various details which I don't recall clearly at the moment, that one obtains the following picture of $\hat{G}$ as a topological space: one has a homeomorphic copy of the open interval $(0,1)$, which one thinks of as "the top half of ${\mathbb T}=\widehat{\mathbb Z}$", and where each point is a 2-dim irrep; as one takes $t\searrow 0$ one converges to TWO distinct 1-dim irreps, each of which is a non-closed point in $\hat{G}$; and the same phenomenon occurs as one takes $t\nearrow 1$.

Comment: Are you sure the endpoints are non-closed points? I thought the spectrum of a liminal algebra was always T1.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. The points are closed, but they cannot be separated by open neighbourhoods

Comment: If every irreducible representation is on Hilbert spaces of the same cardinality (which may be achieved by stabilisation), then the space of isomorphism classes of irreducible representations is a quotient of a subspace of $Hom(A, K(H))$ by the action of the group $U(H)$. Then, $Hom(A,K(H))$ has a tautological $K(H)$ bundle and $A$ maps into the $U(H)$-invariant sections of this bundle. This map is definitely injective, but I am not sure if it is surjective.